# Is it possible to route to www.site.com/username?

Tags: routing

So what I'd like is:

If URI would look like {username}, load _thisTemplate.

Couldn't find the way without solid point like author ID.

Comment: Had the same issue, had to work around like: `/people/phil-collins/832` ...

Comment: One of the options, yes. I doubt, that it is possible yet. The craft needs to know, what user is the click link to and without assigning an user's ID, I think it's impossible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not particularly advise creating a uri pattern that was just 'www.site.com/username' because usernames can essentially be anything which might cause routing conflicts (i.e. if the username is 'index' for example). You could however use something like 'www.site.com/members/username' or 'www.site.com/u/username'.

One way to do this would be to add a route using a 'subpattern'. For more info check out the routing docs on [accessing subpatterns in your templates](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#accessing-subpatterns-in-your-templates).

Here is the example given in the docs, which provides the variables 'year' and 'month' to the template that correspond to the matched uri segments (i.e.  `news/2015/02'):

```
'news/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})' => 'news/_archive',
```

You could essentially do the same thing but with a 'username' variable.

```
'u/(?P<username>[^\/]+)' => '_thisTemplate',
```

You can then use the 'username' variable in your template to retrieve the corresponding user.

```
{% set user = craft.users.username(username).first() %}
{% if user %}
    {{ user.firstName }}
    ...
{% else %}
    {% redirect 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Note that by ```{% set user %}``` you're overwriting Craft's global ```user``` variable (i.e. _the currently logged in user_). Not a problem in most cases, but probably worth mentioning.

Comment: @mmikkel Good point. Although, 'currentUser' would still refer correctly to the currently logged in user, which I believe is the recommended usage anyway.

Comment: To match everything but a slash for a URL pattern use this regular expression: `(?P<username>[^\/]+)`

Comment: Thanks for the addition @carlcs. You also made me realize that I had an error in my expression, which was still expecting 4 digits. Corrected.

Comment: For the given example above, How would you construct the link? `<a href="{{ url('u/' ~ entry.author.username) }}">{{ entry.author.username }}</a>` is what I have, but with `404` redirection.  But anyway, some time ago I posted the question, if there would be possible to add a prefix to variable, like popular '#username'. In this case we wouldn't have to worry about any conflicts. Thanks to @Douglas McDonald, @mmikkel and @carlcs on participating this answer.

Comment: Yes. The link you posted in your comment looks correct. As for the extra character, the pound sign "#", as you probably know, is reserved for anchor tag links — so I would suggest using something else at a minimum, perhaps dash "-" or underscore "_". Although the best in my opinion is still a subpath such as "/u/username".

Comment: Yes, a subpath is very good insurance. And I think, I leave it like that. Also I've voted to reopen [the question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9909/is-it-achievable-to-route-a-dynamic-uri-with-special-character) as it builds to this comment conversation.